# Libgdx TextField text doesn't appear until enter or space is typed

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textfield

Unfortunately I don't have full insight into the causes here, because it is happening on customer's devices which I do not have access to.  That being said, I have multiple reports of text not appearing in a standard libgdx TextField until enter or space is pressed.  Textfield works as desired on my (older) devices as well as an API level 23 emulator.  As such I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Customer info:

1) Country: UK Phone: S7 Edge Root: No Keyboard: Built in Android version: 6.0.1

2) Country: US Phone: S7 Root: No Keyboard: Built in Android version: 6.0.1

I am using the latest release version of Libgdx.
Does anyone know what might cause this, or a work around?